# C file optimization

Tags: c, buffer, posix

I have the following head file code and I am looking for optimization.
How i can rewrite the code using POSIX functions without user-space buffering, without reading character by character but fixed lengths? This I think will improve the efficiency of the code.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("<sintaxa(%s)> fisier \n",argv[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        FILE * file;
        if((file = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL )
            printf(" file %s open error\n",argv[0]);
        fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET);
        while(count < 10)
        {
            fseek(file,-2,SEEK_SET);
            if(ftell(file)<0L)
                break;
            char now = fgetc(file);
            printf("%c",now);
            if(now == '\n')
                ++count;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion (not related to your question): instead of `printf(...argv[1]...)` when `fopen()` fails use `perror(argv[1]);` **and** `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, you can use fread to read directly a block of memory